# Disable autocomplete in django-crispy-forms PrendedText Field

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am using django-crispy-forms and wondering how to disable autocomplete for a specific field. The field is a `forms.IntegerField` that is prependedtext.

```
p_number = forms.IntegerField()

helper = FormHelper()
helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'

helper.layout = Layout(
    Row(
        PrependedText('p_number', 'P',css_class='input-xlarge'),
        Submit('submit','Submit', css_class='btn-primary'),
    )
)
```

Comment: You should inform us if you are using bootstrap or uniform. If you use bootstrap, have you tried with: `p_number = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'off'}))` ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap. If I am use the widget as a TextInput will it still only accept numbers?

Comment: The [Integer field defaults widget is textImput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield). Also, have you tried my approach?

Comment: @danihp I have not, I tried it similar with an IntegerField but not TextInput. I will try it and get back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap has `autocomplete` input attibute to allow disable autocomplete. You can set to off this attribute through django-crispy-forms in this way:

```
p_number = forms.IntegerField(
               widget=forms.TextInput(
                                  attrs={'autocomplete':'off',}
                                     )
                              )
```

Answer (score 9):

The crispy-forms way of doing this would be as easy as:

```
PrependedText('p_number', 'P', css_class='input-xlarge', autocomplete="off"),
```

Comment: +1: this should be the right answer if project owner say it ;)

Comment: This is the documented solution and should be accepted as the correct answer. See https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#layout-objects-attributes